# how to deal with "CORS error" when writing firefox plugin?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to write a plugin for Firefox that keeps track of changes of several websites.  To do this, I would need to maintain a list of websites and do "HTTP GET" to get their latest contents using following code:

```js
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.withCredentials = true;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

However, I constantly have following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

Does anyone know how I should fix this issue?  Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow Cross-Origin requests for an extension you are developing, you need to request the permission in your `manifest.json`. The documentation can be found here: [permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#host_permissions) and [host_permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/host_permissions). This, I quote, grants the permission for:

> XMLHttpRequest and fetch access to those origins without cross-origin restrictions (even for requests made from content scripts).

You need to add the websites you want to use fetch requests on, as [match patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns), for example: `*://*.google.com/*` will grant you fetch request permissions for google.com and its subdomains (such as maps.google.com), on HTTP and HTTPS. If you want to request permissions for all websites, you can use the special pattern `<all_urls>`.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you mean I need to add something like `"permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "<all_urls>"],` ?

Comment: No, I suggest you read the documentation links I posted, especially the one for `host_permissions`. `<all_urls>` needs to be added to the `host_permissions` property, like so: `"host_permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ]`.

Comment: Thanks!  it looks like host_permissions only works for V3, is it possible to do similar things in V2?

Comment: Yes! My bad, for v2 you have to use it the way you said: `"permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "<all_urls>"]`. However I am not 100% sure if `<all_urls>` still works - maybe, if that doesn't work you can try `*://*/*`.